# Why does NOOBS only list two operating systems to install?

Tags: noobs

So I downloaded NOOBS on my 32 GB SD card, but I only have Raspbian and some movie watching OS to choose from.

When I look at other people's NOOBS online, they have a whole list—why is that? Do I have to manually add new operating systems to NOOBS?

Answer (score 1):

You need to connect to the Internet, using WiFi or the Ethernet port on the device to connect to the Internet. Once you are connected there are many options are available, as noted in the [documentation](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/installation/noobs.md):

> As of NOOBS v1.3.10 (September 2014), only Raspbian is installed by default in NOOBS. The others can be installed with a network connection.

Answer (score 0):

Some operating systems will only be displayed with a working internet connection. The reason is that they need to be downloaded on-the-fly and are not actually included in the main NOOBS zip file.